# Why does Visual Studio refuse to debug my ASP.NET application and attempts to attach to my browser instead

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I recently reinstalled visual studio 2015, and for some reason I can't start the debugger for an asp.net web application by pressing F5 as I used to do. Visual studio is trying to attach to my firefox.exe process ; at first it was complaining that the process was 64bits, and now I solved that it wants me to set a "start page" which I don't want to, and it doesn't start the web server in debug mode anyway. Which means I can't set breakpoints or catch exceptions in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that `ASP.NET` was not checked in the project properties in the `Web` tab. This is needed to enable server-side debugging.

Instead, `Silverlight` was checked, which caused visual studio to try to attach to the browser. I never, ever, wrote anything related to silverlight, I have no idea why this was checked, as far as I know I didn't even open the properties page since I reinstalled visual studio.